# Field has a strange behavior if I don't use method:

Tags: graphql-ruby

I am using graphql-ruby gem v 1.9.6 with the class-version base. I am using 2 models. See below.

model 1 :

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  include EnsureUUID

  has_secure_password

  has_one :freelancer, dependent: :destroy ....
```

model 2 :

```
class Freelancer < ApplicationRecord
  include EnsureUUID

    belongs_to :user
    validates_uniqueness_of :user_id
end
```

if I write :

```
field :from_user, UserType, null: true, method: :user
```

in my freelancer_type declaration all is ok !

if I write :

```
field :from_user, UserType, null: true
```

schema is BAD !

My question is what is "method:  :user" doing ?? I couldn't find in documentation...

Answer (score 0):

You can just do

```
field :user, UserType, null: true
```

which will work!

ok what does **method** do?

It acts like an alias for field name provided, field name here is `from_user` which I believe caller(front-end) knows/identifies/wants to be.

```
field :from_user, UserType, null: true, method: :user
```